# Tightness of an inequality

Tags: inequality

I have an inequality with $a_n>0\forall n$ and $A_n\geq a_n\forall n$ that 
\begin{equation}
\sum^N_{n=1}a_n\frac{a_n}{A_n}\geq \frac{(\sum^N_{n=1}a_n)^2}{\sum^N_{n=1}A_n}
\end{equation}
however I am interested in how tight this inequality is. Does anyone have an idea to analyse it?

So far my idea is equality holds when 
\begin{equation}
\frac{a_1}{A_1}=\cdots=\frac{a_N}{A_N}
\end{equation}
but any idea to show how much gap when the strict $>$ holds? For example, I tried to calculate the difference between two sides of inequality, but it becomes very complicated.

Comment: It is sharp: Equality holds when $a_1 = \cdots = a_N = 0$.

Comment: You should include the assumptions about the range allowed for $a_n,A_N$.  For example, it appears that $A_n$ should be positive.  Perhaps there are additional "known" restrictions that affect how "tight" the inequality is.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is just the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality

It is well known (and follows from the proof) that equality occurs iff all numbers are proportional (this is the condition you wrote).